# Colour resource ID returning wrong value

Tags: java, android

I am trying to set the text colour programatically from a colour resource during onCreate and am getting some wierd results.

I have a colour resource defined in res\colors.xml:

```
<resources>

    <color name="wheelFill">#C0FFFFFF</color>

</resources>
```

my activity then uses the following code to retrieve the colour:

```
int WheelColour = getResources().getColor(R.color.wheelFill);
```

Finally I assign it to a Paint:

```
mBackgroundPaint.setColor(WheelColour);
```

When I run my application the colour does not get set an I get a log message from the getColor line claiming that "Color value 'List' must start with #".  'List' is the value of one of my string resources so clearly something is getting messed up there.

If I bypass the resource and use:

```
int WheelColour = Color.argb(0xC0, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
```

Everything works correctly so it has to be the getColor call but I can't see what's wrong with it. (I have tried explicitly using a context which made no difference).

Has anybody else come across this or sucessfully managed to set paint colours from colour resources?

Comment: maybe your R.java got messed up and isn't linking to the correct resource.  clean the project and refresh

Comment: Already tried that but thanks for the suggestion - it has solved a few unexplainable issues in the past.

Comment: Having shut everything down, refreshing a few times then cleaning everything has started working again. so it looks like it was corrupt R.java after all.

Comment: binnyb if you post your comment as an answer I'll accept it. It looks like messing about with the name of my values/color.xml file had corrupted something and a few cleans and refreshes fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe your R.java got messed up and isn't linking to the correct resource. clean the project and refresh